# Event registration without online payment

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

What is the configuration for an paid event that has no online payment option?

I have a Drupal/CiviCRM website running since quite some time for courses I provide. People register online, and only when there are enough people the course takes place. I then send people an invoice (per mail) that they have to pay.

I'm now stuck with a bug where I receive a "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tid' cannot be null" error message, which I have the impression is linked to an error in my event configuration.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more details.  What are the steps to produce this error message? Which versions of Drupal and CiviCRM are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this with the *Pay Later option*.

1. Navigate to the *Fees* tab.
2. Enable *Paid Event*
3. Check the Pay Later Option

[image: Pay later Option on a CiviRM Event]